# bash - shuffle a file that is too large to fit in memory

Tags: bash

I've got a file that's too large to fit in memory. `shuf` seems to run in RAM, and `sort -R` doesn't shuffle (identical lines end up next to each other; I need all of the lines to be shuffled). Are there any options other than rolling my own solution?

Comment: Also: `sort -R` is [much slower](https://github.com/miku/rsampling#comparison-to-sort-and-shuf) than shuf (if shuf runs).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using a form of [decorate-sort-undecorate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) pattern and `awk` you can do something like:

```
$ seq 10 | awk 'BEGIN{srand();} {printf "%06d %s\n", rand()*1000000, $0;}' | sort -n | cut -c8-
8
5
1
9
6
3
7
2
10
4
```

For a file, you would do:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{srand();} {printf "%06d %s\n", rand()*1000000, $0;}' SORTED.TXT | sort -n | cut -c8- > SHUFFLED.TXT
```

or `cat` the file at the start of the pipeline.

This works by generating a column of random numbers between `000000` and `999999` inclusive (decorate); sorting on that column (sort); then deleting the column (undecorate). That should work on platforms where sort does not understand numerics by generating a column with leading zeros for lexicographic sorting.

You can increase that randomization, if desired, in several ways:

1. If your platform's `sort` understands numerical values (POSIX, GNU and BSD do) you can do `awk 'BEGIN{srand();} {printf "%0.15f\t%s\n", rand(), $0;}' FILE.TXT | sort -n | cut  -f 2-` to use a near double float for random representation.
2. If you are limited to a lexicographic sort, just combine two calls to `rand` into one column like so: `awk 'BEGIN{srand();} {printf "%06d%06d\t%s\n", rand()*1000000,rand()*1000000, $0;}' FILE.TXT | sort -n | cut  -f 2-` which gives a composite 12 digits of randomization.

Comment: Nice. Because `sort` splits into multiple files to process contents larger than will fit in memory (the GNU version, anyhow), this should actually work.

Comment: +1 -- good idea. Note that since `sort` performs a stable sort, this won't be a 100% perfect shuffle: if line A comes before line B in the input, this approach is slightly more likely to put line A before line B in the output. To fix this, you can invert the numbering and shuffling, by writing something like `seq 10 | grep -n '' | sort -R | cut -d: -f2-` instead. (But even without that change, I think it's probably fine: I think it should be quite close to a random ordering.)

Comment: @ruakh: Thanks. You are right -- it does have a slight tendency to maintain order because of `sort` having a stable sort. It does have random digits between 0 and 1000000 so this would only be an issue with the same random number on two lines in a row. Another way to make it more random is to add more digits or a second column of random digits.

Comment: @dawg: Re: "this would only be an issue with the same random number on two lines in a row": It would be an issue if the same random number occurs multiple times, period, regardless of whether they're "in a row". (So it's guaranteed to be an issue, albeit a minor one, on any file with a large number of rows.)

Comment: (Though my original comment was partly wrong: by default, `sort` actually *doesn't* do a stable sort, but rather, does a last-resort comparison of the entire line. So it will still be slightly wrong, but in a different way than what I said: if line A comes before line B *in lexicographic order*, then this approach is slightly more likely to put line A before line B in the output.)

Comment: @ruakh: Agreed.

Comment: To speed this up, you can replace `awk` by `paste <(shuf -i1-$(wc -l < bigfile)) bigfile`. You may also want to use `-S ...`, `--parallel` and maybe `LC_ALL=C` on `sort`.

Answer (score 5):

Count lines (`wc -l`) and generate a list of numbers corresponding to line numbers, in a random order - perhaps by generating a list of numbers in a temp file (use `/tmp/`, which is in RAM typically, and thus relatively fast). Then copy the line corresponding to each number to the target file in the order of the shuffled numbers.

This would be time-inefficient, because of the amount of seeking for newlines in the file, but it would work on almost any size of file.

Comment: this doesn't seem that time inefficient to me, especially if the file is memmapped

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at https://github.com/alexandres/terashuf . From page:

> terashuf implements a quasi-shuffle algorithm for shuffling
>   multi-terabyte text files using limited memory

Comment: Please have a look at the issue you created on Github. I believe you don't have enough free disk space for the temporary files required to execute the shuffle.

Comment: Not affiliated, just a fan: terashuf works as advertised, does intelligent estimation of expected memory usage, seems efficient (though single-threaded), lets you configure how much RAM to use per chunk, and can handle files dramatically larger than physical RAM.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I would say, this is not a strict global shuffle solution.

Generally, my idea is to split the large file into smaller ones, and then do the shuffle.

1. **Split** large file into pieces:

`split -bytes=500M large_file small_file_`

This will split your large_file into small_file_aa, small_file_ab....

2. **Shuffle**:

`shuf small_file_aa > small_file_aa.shuf`

You may try to blend the files several times to get a result approximate to global shuffle.

Answer (score 2):

If the file is within a few orders of magnitude of what can fit in memory, one option is to randomly distribute the lines among (say) 1000 temporary files, then shuffle each of those files and concatenate the result:

```
perl -we ' my $NUM_FILES = 1000;
           my @fhs;
           for (my $i = 0; $i < $NUM_FILES; ++$i) {
             open $fh[$i], "> tmp.$i.txt"
               or die "Error opening tmp.$i.txt: $!";
           }
           while (<>) {
             $fh[int rand $NUM_FILES]->print($_);
           }
           foreach my $fh (@fhs) {
             close $fh;
           }
         ' < input.txt \
&& \
for tmp_file in tmp.*.txt ; do
  shuf ./"$tmp_file" && rm ./"$tmp_file"
done > output.txt
```

(Of course, there will be some variation in the sizes of the temporary files — they won't all be *exactly* one-thousandth the size of the original file — so if you use this approach, you need to give yourself some buffer by erring on the side of more, smaller files.)

Comment: Pardon the initial misread -- I hope the downvoter didn't trust my faulty  analysis. This is a perfectly reasonable approach.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: No worries. I'm *guessing* the downvoter was actually l'L'l. (And even if not, I now think that dawg's answer is a better approach than mine, so I'm not too attached to this answer. :-P )

Answer (score 0):

How about:
`perl <large-input-file -lne 'print rand(), "\t", $_' | sort | perl -lpe 's/^.*?\t//' >shuffled-output-file`

Answer (score 0):

If it's acceptable to permutate within some boundaries, you can use `split` with `--filter` option where you can use `shuf`:

```
zcat huge.gz | split -l 1000000 --filter='shuf | gzip > $FILE.gz' - huge-
```

With `-l` option you can regulate how many lines to permutate in a batch.