# How do you randomize rows in a memory efficient manner?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk

I have a text as shown below and is about 6gb in size. I want to keep rows upto `#CHROM` unchanged, but I want to shuffle all rows below row `#CHROM`. Is there a memory efficient way to do this?

```
##contig=<ID=chrX,length=155270560,assembly=hg19>
##contig=<ID=chrY,length=59373566,assembly=hg19>
##contig=<ID=chrM,length=16571,assembly=hg19>
##reference=file:///dmf/
##source=SelectVariants
#CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT     QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT
chr1    14165   .       A       G       220.12  VQSRTrancheSNP99.90to10
chr1    14248   .       T       G       547.33  VQSRTrancheSNP99.90to10
chr1    14354   .       C       A       2942.62 VQSRTrancheSNP99.90to10
chr1    14374   .       A       G       17.90   VQSRTrancheSNP99.90to10
```

The result I want would look like this:

```
##contig=<ID=chrX,length=155270560,assembly=hg19>
##contig=<ID=chrY,length=59373566,assembly=hg19>
##contig=<ID=chrM,length=16571,assembly=hg19>
##reference=file:///dmf/
##source=SelectVariants
#CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT     QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT
chr1    14354   .       C       A       2942.62 VQSRTrancheSNP99.90to10
chr1    14248   .       T       G       547.33  VQSRTrancheSNP99.90to10
chr1    14374   .       A       G       17.90   VQSRTrancheSNP99.90to10
chr1    14165   .       A       G       220.12  VQSRTrancheSNP99.90to10
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40814785/522479 could be interesting.

Comment: depends on how you will use the rows eventually and how random you want them to be.  If some local affinity is allowed, you can chunk the data portion, shuf each piece and join the chunks in random order.

Answer (score 2):

I would split the file by your criteria, use `shuf` on the second chunk, and cat them together again. I can't think of a memory efficient wat that would avoid the splitting.

Comment: Thanks! Wouldn't `shuf` shlows down if the rows are more than 37000 rows?

Comment: I haven't operated shuf on files that size, wouldn't know. But as it's part of coreutils I'd at least give it a shot ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one in awk:

```
awk -v seed=$RANDOM '              # get a random seed to srand()
BEGIN {
    srand(seed)                    
}
/^#/ {                             # print all # starting, no need to store them to mem
    print                          # this could be more clever but not the point
    next                           # in this solution
}
{
    r=rand()                        # get a random value for hash key
    a[r]=a[r] (a[r]==""?"":ORS) $0  # hash to a, append if key collision
}
END {
    for(i in a)                     # in the end print in awk implementation default order
        print a[i]                  # randomness was created while hashing
}' file
```

AN output:

```
##contig=<ID=chrX,length=155270560,assembly=hg19>
##contig=<ID=chrY,length=59373566,assembly=hg19>
##contig=<ID=chrM,length=16571,assembly=hg19>
##reference=file:///dmf/
##source=SelectVariants
#CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT     QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT
chr1    14165   .       A       G       220.12  VQSRTrancheSNP99.90to10
chr1    14354   .       C       A       2942.62 VQSRTrancheSNP99.90to10
chr1    14248   .       T       G       547.33  VQSRTrancheSNP99.90to10
chr1    14374   .       A       G       17.90   VQSRTrancheSNP99.90to10
```

It will load all non-`#`-starting records to memory. If you try it, please let us know how big the memory image grows.

**Update**:

Here is another with a small modification to the above:

```
BEGIN {
    srand(seed)
}
/^#/ {
    print
    next
}
{
    r=rand()
    a[r]=a[r] (a[r]==""?"":ORS) $0
}
NR>1000 {             # the first 1000 records are hashed above
    for(i in a) {     # after that 
        print a[i]    # a "random" one is printed
        delete a[i]   # and deleted from the hash
        break         # only a 1000 records is kept in memory
    }
}
END {
    for(i in a)
        print a[i]
}
```

Since I'm using `NR` that includes the `#` starting records also so a 1000 records is not the exact amount of records in the hash. Choose a value to your liking.

Here is a sample output with `NR>10` and `seq 1 20`:

```
$ seq 1 20 | awk -v seed=$RANDOM -f script.awk  
3
9
13
2
1
16
17
14
10
20
15
7
19
5
18
12
11
6
4
8
```

Comment: that algorithm will favor early records to show up early, not close to uniform.  For example there is zero change that `20` will show up in the first lines.

Comment: Sure. Run a full random version if you have the memory or 1 to several runs of the memory saving version.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're on Linux, you probably have GNU `sort -R` to randomize.

GNU sort will automatically use disk space instead of RAM when required, so it can sort/randomize hundreds of gigabytes on systems with much less RAM.